# Get all the rows from query result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that returns a boolean. (0 or 1). It returns multiple rows. my question is how to iterate through all the result.

```
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBReader"].ConnectionString))
  {
       using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Reader.usp_CheckerIsStopped", con))
       {
           com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           com.Parameters.Add("@fld_UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.UserID;

           con.Open();
           SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

           if (dr.Read() == 1)
           {
               return true;
           }
           else
           {
               return false;
           }
      }
  }
```

It has a error in `dr.Read() == 1`

**Error:**

> Operator == cannot be applied to type bool to int"

My stored procedure returns multiple rows containing 0 or 1,I want to get those values because I want to do a checking if it is equals to true of false (0 or 1)

```
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //if (e.Row.Cells[11].Text == "In Progress")
            //{
            //    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton StartImageButton = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("StartImageButton");
            //    StartImageButton.Visible = false;
            //}
            gvfunct.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
            gvfunct.CheckIsStopped();
            if (gvfunct.CheckIsStopped() == true)
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton StartImageButton = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("StartImageButton");
                StartImageButton.Visible = true;
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton StopImageButton = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("StopImageButton");
                StopImageButton.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton StopImageButton = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("StopImageButton");
                StopImageButton.Visible = true;
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton StartImageButton = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("StartImageButton");
                StartImageButton.Visible = false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: what does the result set look like? `Read` only advances the pointer in each row.

Comment: returns a boolean or returns multiple rows?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to return all the rows, or just a single result? If it is one result then what does that result represent?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to continue to `Read()` and do something with those results.

```
while (dr.Read())
{

}
```

You see, the `Read()` method returns a `bool`. So, now if you wanted to get to the results of each row you might do something like this:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    var val = dr.GetInt32(0);
}
```

and that would get the value of the first column, from the row you're currently on in the `Read()`, and cast it as an `int`. Of course that line could throw an error if you're trying to cast a `string` or something. Consider the fact that a `DataReader` is a read-only, forward-only, buffer of data. It literally only pulls one row of data at a time from the server, thus leaving the connection open during the duration of the `Read()` operation and until it goes out of scope.

Comment: If i do this, how will I return true or false? while doesnt have an Else condition

Comment: @user1954418, you will have to set a `bool result;` variable and return it. The logic you have, even in your example, doesn't work to return a single `true` or `false` over many records. You need to flesh out that logic, but if you need to iterate many records, you need to leverage the `while` because `Read()` returns a `true` or a `false` (i.e. continue reading or not because I have/have not reached the end).

Answer (score 0):

As `dr.Read()` returns `bool` thus you are getting error when comparing with `int`

It will return true if SqlDataReader has rows otherwise false.

So change you code as

```
return dr.Read();
```

instead of

```
if (dr.Read() == 1)
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: `dr.Read()` only returns true if `dr` has another row to read. And `dr.Read()` reads that row and will read the next row of the data reader.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (dr.Read() == 1)
{
    return true;
}
```

with

```
 if (dr.Read())
 {
    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to explicitly cast it or just use it's proper Boolean type
so instead of `if (dr.Read() == 1)`, you may use `if (dr.Read() == true)` or `if (dr.Read())`

there isn't a direct cast that i am aware of, for instance `(bool)1` is not going to work, but you may always use `Convert.ToBoolean(1)` or some other methods to convert it

you may also create your own custom casting method

```
IntToBool (int bool)
{
  if(bool == 1) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what your stored procedure returns, but if the first row and first column contains for example an integer, you could also forget the reader and use [SqlCommands ExecuteScalar-method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) like so:

```
return com.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to iterate through all the rows, try this

```
if(dr.Read()){
 if(dr.Read()) return true;
 else return false;
}
else return false;
```

This will read dr twice and return true if it finds 2 rows. False if it finds 0 or 1 row.